# C Server stops responding when client disconnects

Tags: c, sockets, pthreads

I have written a fairly simple C chat server with the use of pthreads.
Server works without any problem, client connects to it using telnet and then clients can communicate with each other. Each client is started within its own thread.
The problem arises, when any of the clients desides to disconnect. Even though i close client socket and finish its thread (which it does, or at least gdb says so) this disturbance somehow closes all communication on the server side, even though other threads are still running. After this, clients cannot communicate with each other and thus rendering server quite useless.
I do not know how to fix this and i ask for your help.
Thank you.

Here is my code. I include full code for i am not certain where is my mistake

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h> 
#include <string.h> 
#include <errno.h>  
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <pthread.h>

int user[30];     // sockets of connected users
char names[30][20];
int user_count=0; // number of active connections
int listen_sock;  // main socket, recieves connections
char buffer[500];
pthread_t *thready[30];
pthread_mutex_t mutex;


struct arg_struct {
    int arg1;
    int arg2;
};

void sending(char *text, int i) {
  char buffer2[504];
  strcpy(buffer2, "\r\0");
  strcat(buffer2, text);
  strcat(buffer2, "\r\0");
  write(user[i], buffer2, strlen(buffer2));
}

void welcome(int id) {
  int len;
  int sock;
  char name[20];
  pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
  sock = user[id];

  write(sock,"\rEnter your name: ", 18);
  // Read returns number of characters recieved
  len = read(sock,name,20);
  // Add zero to the end of string (read doesnt do it)
  name[len]='\0';

  while (name[len] < 32) 
  { 
    name[len]='\0';
    len--;
  }

//  snprintf(buffer,"Welcome %s!\n",name);
  write(sock, "Welcome\r\n", 7);
  strcpy(names[id], name);
  sending(buffer,id);
  pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
}

void echo(char *text) {
  int i; 
  for (i=0; i<user_count; i++) {
    sending(text, i);
  }
}

void disconnect(int id) {
  int i;
  char deadname[20];

  strcpy(deadname,names[id]);
  sending("You have been disconnected\n",id);
  shutdown(user[id], SHUT_RDWR);
  close(user[id]);
  for (i=id; i<user_count-1; i++) { 
    user[i]=user[i+1];
    strcpy(names[i],names[i+1]);
  }
  user_count--;
  sprintf(buffer,"%s has disconnected\n",deadname);
  echo(buffer);
}

void finish() {
  echo("Shuting down, disconnecting everyone!\n");
  while (user_count > 0) disconnect(user_count-1);
  shutdown(listen_sock, SHUT_RDWR);
  close(listen_sock);
  pthread_mutex_destroy(&mutex);
  exit(0);
}

void getcomm(char *inpstr, char *comm) { /* First letter from inpstr goes to comm,
                                            and is removed from inpstr */
  int wpos=0,leng;                      /* Splits first word from the rest of the sentence */
  char *zal;

  zal=inpstr;
  leng=strlen(zal);

  while (*inpstr>32 && wpos<14) {
    *comm=*inpstr++;
    comm++;
    wpos++;
  }
  inpstr=(char *)memmove(zal,inpstr+1,leng);
  *comm='\0';
}

void input(int id) {

}

void* communication(void* par){
    int sock = ((int*)par)[0];
    int id = ((int*)par)[1];
    free((int*)par);
    welcome(id);
    while(1){
      char line[500];
      char command[20];
      char name2[16];
      int len,sock;

      // 1. read line from user
      len=read(user[id],line,499);
      pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
      line[len]='\0';
      if (len == 0) {  // User has terminated the connection
        continue;
      }

      while (line[len] < 32) { // Remove special chars
        line[len]='\0';
        len--;
      }

      // 2. Get first word
      getcomm(line,command);

      // 3. Recognise command and execute it
      len=strlen(command);
      if (strncmp(command,"quit",4) == 0) {
        disconnect(id);
        pthread_exit(NULL);
      }
      else if (!strncmp(command,"tell",len)) {
        getcomm(line,name2);
        sprintf(buffer,"%s tells %s: %s\n", names[id], name2, line);
        echo(buffer);
      }
      else if (!strncmp(command,"shut",len)) {
        finish();
      }
      // 4. Unknown command
      else {
        sprintf(buffer,"%s tells %s %s\n", names[id], command, line);
        echo(buffer);
      }
      pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
    }
}

int main( int argc, char *argv[] ) {
  int pid;
  struct sockaddr_in bind_addr;
  struct sockaddr_in acc_addr;
  int size, user_id, i, sel,on;
  int port_number;
  char * eptr = NULL;
  fd_set readmask;
  pthread_mutexattr_t attr;
  pthread_mutexattr_init(&attr);
  pthread_mutex_init(&mutex, NULL);

  listen_sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
  if (listen_sock==-1) {
    perror("socket()");
    pthread_mutex_destroy(&mutex);
    exit(-1);
  }
  on = 1;
  if (argc == 1){
    perror("Please specify port number");
    pthread_mutex_destroy(&mutex);
    //exit(0);
  } 
  if (argc == 2){
    port_number = (int) strtol(argv[1], &eptr, 10);
    if (*eptr != '\0'){
      perror("Invalid Port Number!");
        pthread_mutex_destroy(&mutex);
      exit(-1);
    }
  }
  port_number = 7501;

  bind_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
  bind_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
  bind_addr.sin_port = htons(port_number);
  size=sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
  setsockopt(listen_sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, (char *)&on, sizeof(on));

  if (bind(listen_sock, (struct sockaddr *)&bind_addr, size)==-1) {
    perror("bind()");
    pthread_mutex_destroy(&mutex);
    exit(-1);
  }

  listen(listen_sock, 10);

  while(1) {
      FD_ZERO(&readmask);
      FD_SET(listen_sock, &readmask);
      if (FD_ISSET(listen_sock, &readmask)) {
          user_id = user_count++;
          int * soc = (int*)malloc(2*sizeof(int));

          soc[0] = accept(listen_sock,(struct sockaddr *)&acc_addr, &size);
          soc[1] = user_id;
          pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
          user[user_id] = soc[0];

          pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);

          if( ( pthread_create( &thready[user_id], NULL, communication, (void*)soc ) ) < 0)
                {
                    perror("could not create thread");
                    return 1;
                } 
            echo(buffer);
          continue;
    }
  }

  pthread_mutex_destroy(&mutex);
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You seem to not unlock mutex before calling pthread_exit(). This should block all your other communication threads.

Also, did you miss select() call after FD_SET()?